# Same datasource multiple times but other database driver

Tags: docker, wildfly

I am using a `WILDFLY` server that uses a `standalone.xml` configured with the same datasource multiple times, but with different database specifications, namely postgreSQL, DB2, H2 and OracleDB:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources>
   <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/demoDS" pool-name="demoDS-db2" enabled="true" use-ccm="true" statistics-enabled="false">
      <connection-url>${env.DB_CONNECTION_URL}</connection-url>
      <driver>db2</driver>
      <security>
         <user-name>${env.DB_USER}</user-name>
         <password>${env.DB_PASSWORD}</password>
      </security>
   </datasource>
   <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/demoDS" pool-name="demoDS-postgresql" enabled="true" use-ccm="true" statistics-enabled="false">
      <connection-url>${env.DB_CONNECTION_URL}</connection-url>
      <driver>postgresql</driver>
      <security>
         <user-name>${env.DB_USER}</user-name>
         <password>${env.DB_PASSWORD}</password>
      </security>
   </datasource>
   <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/demoDS" pool-name="demoDS-H2" enabled="true" use-ccm="true" statistics-enabled="false">
      <connection-url>${env.DB_CONNECTION_URL}</connection-url>
      <driver>h2</driver>
      <security>
         <user-name>${env.DB_USER}</user-name>
         <password>${env.DB_PASSWORD}</password>
      </security>
   </datasource>
   <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/demoDS" pool-name="demoDS-Oracle" enabled="true" use-ccm="true" statistics-enabled="false">
      <connection-url>${env.DB_CONNECTION_URL}</connection-url>
      <driver>oracle</driver>
      <security>
         <user-name>${env.DB_USER}</user-name>
         <password>${env.DB_PASSWORD}</password>
      </security>
   </datasource>
</datasources>
```

This is done in order to test the deployed application with multiple database providers.

#### The problem

As i have multiple datasources `enabled` that use the same identifier, the deployment will fail saying `demoDS` has already been registered. My question is now how it is possible to dynamically decide which datasource to use. Of course one could always set one datasource to `enabled="true"` and all others to `enabled="false"` but this is not a local WILDFLY server, it is a `docker` container and therefore this is not easily possible.

I want to avoid building one image per datasource as well because I have 3 applications that share this requirement, which would result in 12 docker images.

Any idea on how this could be solved as elegantly as possible?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any volumes mounted?

Comment: Nah, i dont have any volumes mounted

Comment: If you did you could change the `standalone.xml` **outside** of the docker, using a shell type script to update it to what you want.  Then you could start the docker.  Alternatively, you could simply have 12 `standalone.xml` files and one docker.